# Add prefix folder name to each file inside of the zip

Tags: 22.04, zip

I want to zip all files recursively but adding some prefix folder in front.

I tried:

```bash
zip -rq test.zip node_modules --prefix nodejs/
```

But getting error: `zip error: Invalid command arguments (long option 'prefix' not supported)`

Also tried with --transform, which seems to be not working in linux too.

My goal that all files with sub folders in `node_modules/*` should be with `nodejs/node_modules/*` path inside of a zip file

For the moment I'm using a hard way to do it:

```bash
mkdir nodejs
mv node_modules nodejs/
zip -rq ./$OUTPUT_DIR/dep-$DEP_VERSION.zip nodejs
mv nodejs/node_modules ./
rm -r nodejs
```

But I'm looking for more elegant solution.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1750334/create-zip-archive-with-path-prefix

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK [`zip`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/zip.1.html) doesn't have an option for that, but [`tar`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/tar.1.html) does have:

> ```
> --transform, --xform EXPRESSION
>   use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names.
> ```

So:

```bash
$ mkdir node_modules
$ touch node_modules/file{1..3}
$ tree node_modules/
node_modules/
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3

0 directories, 3 files
$
$ tar czf test.tgz --transform 's|^|nodejs/|' node_modules/
$ tar -tf test.tgz 
nodejs/node_modules/
nodejs/node_modules/file2
nodejs/node_modules/file3
nodejs/node_modules/file1
$
$ tar xf test.tgz
$ tree nodejs/
nodejs/
└── node_modules
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3

1 directory, 3 files
```

If however your end result must be a `zip` archive then you can use `tar` without compression to save time and resources then extract the archive and compress it with `zip` afterwards ... Or you can use a function that will automatically do this for you like this:

```bash
my_zip () {
p="$1" # First argument "archive prefix directory name"
d="$2" # Second argument "source directory name"
z="$3" # Third argument "result ZIP archive name without .zip"
[ -e "$p" -o -e "${z}.zip" ] && return "Prefix directory name: $p Or target zip file name: ${z}.zip exist in PWD, cannot continue"
tmp="$(mktemp)"
tar cf "$tmp" --transform "s|^|$p/|" "$d"
tar xf "$tmp"
zip -rq "${z}.zip" "$p"
rm "$tmp"
rm -r "$p"
}
```

Then use the function by its name `my_zip` passing properly quoted arguments `"prefix"`, `"source_directory"` and `"zip_archive_name"` in that order like so:

```bash
$ my_zip "nodejs2" "node_modules" "test2"
$ unzip -l test2.zip 
Archive:  test2.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2023-04-24 17:11   nodejs2/
        0  2023-04-24 16:58   nodejs2/node_modules/
        0  2023-04-23 19:51   nodejs2/node_modules/file2
        0  2023-04-23 19:51   nodejs2/node_modules/file3
        0  2023-04-23 19:51   nodejs2/node_modules/file1
---------                     -------
        0                     5 files
$
$ unzip -q test2.zip
$ tree nodejs2/
nodejs2/
└── node_modules
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3

1 directory, 3 files
```

Comment: Any way to convert it to zip file? I'm not sure if tgz will be supported for what I need.

Comment: @Kostanos I updated the answer with a function that I wrote to do that ... Unfortunately no utility/package in the repositories can do that AFAIK.

Comment: Oh man, it is unzipping and zipping again, doesn't make sens.
In this case, it is easier copy folder to necessary path, zip it and delete after.
Or even faster move it, zip it, and move it back. Any way, thank you for trying